# Question Title is not shown in Google results

Tags: bug

Question title is not shown in Google results. Instead it shows the `Votes Count` - `Site name`. Please refer the screenshot below:

[image]

Search URL: https://www.google.com/search?q=sshconfig+file+add+password&oq=sshconfig+file+add+password

Comment: Re the duplicate: What is the gist of it? A problem that comes and goes?